# External php file/link in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, external

I want to display this

http://www.bwbsv.de/bbsb/service/extern/standings.php?start=http://www.bwbsv.de/bbsb/service/extern/start.htm&end=http://www.bwbsv.de/bbsb/service/extern/end.htm&t=401

(this is just an example)
on a page of my wordpress site. 
The start.htm contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Demonstration Tabellen-Integration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://www.bwbsv.de/bbsb/service/extern/demo.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

while the end.htm looks like

```
</body>
</html>
```

The "t=401" specifies what league to display.

What would be the best way to implement this into a page?

EDIT: I forgot somehing. The url of the start.htm and end.htm are stored localy while the standings.php isn't. the point of this is to have an up to date league table, whithout doing it manually.

EDIT 2: To clarify further: 
The first link is just an example of how it should look like. It can be customized to fit the users needs with for example t=401 means the league with id=401. After customization it should look something like this

http://www.bwbsv.de/bbsb/service/extern/standings.php?start=http:/yourServer.com/start.htm&end=http://http:/yourServer.com/end.htm&t=123

This link provides an up to date league table of the league with id 123. The updates are not done by me, they are provided from the bwbsv page. I want to integrate this table into an normal page/widget/sidebar/... on my wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my first post, due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you cant load external content, sorry.

Use `jQuery` [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Give the table an `id` of `league-table` and then:

```
$('#league-table').load('path/to/your_file');
```

Here is a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Demonstration Tabellen-Integration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://www.bwbsv.de/bbsb/service/extern/demo.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("here");
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("here");
  $('#league').load('path_to_your_file.html');
  alert("finished loading");
  });

</script>


  <div id="league">

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**File.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Demonstration Tabellen-Integration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://www.bwbsv.de/bbsb/service/extern/demo.css" />
</head>
<body>


<table id="league" class="standings">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th class="hpl">Pl.</th>
        <th class="hteam">Team</th>
        <th class="hg">G</th>
        <th class="hv">V</th>
        <th class="hpct">.pct</th>
        <th class="hgb">GB</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pl">1.</td>
            <td class="team">
              Kehl Mosquitos              
            </td>
            <td class="g">0</td>
            <td class="v">0</td>
            <td class="pct">.000</td>
            <td class="gb">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pl">2.</td>
            <td class="team">
              Ulm Falcons             
            </td>
            <td class="g">0</td>
            <td class="v">0</td>
            <td class="pct">.000</td>
            <td class="gb">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pl">3.</td>
            <td class="team">
              Sindelfingen Squirrels              
            </td>
            <td class="g">0</td>
            <td class="v">0</td>
            <td class="pct">.000</td>
            <td class="gb">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pl">4.</td>
            <td class="team">
              Heidelberg Hedgehogs            
            </td>
            <td class="g">0</td>
            <td class="v">0</td>
            <td class="pct">.000</td>
            <td class="gb">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pl">5.</td>
            <td class="team">
              Schriesheim Raubritter              
            </td>
            <td class="g">0</td>
            <td class="v">0</td>
            <td class="pct">.000</td>
            <td class="gb">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pl">6.</td>
            <td class="team">
              Göppingen Green Sox             
            </td>
            <td class="g">0</td>
            <td class="v">0</td>
            <td class="pct">.000</td>
            <td class="gb">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pl">7.</td>
            <td class="team">
              Freiburg Knights            
            </td>
            <td class="g">0</td>
            <td class="v">0</td>
            <td class="pct">.000</td>
            <td class="gb">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pl">8.</td>
            <td class="team">
              Tübingen Hawks 2            
            </td>
            <td class="g">0</td>
            <td class="v">0</td>
            <td class="pct">.000</td>
            <td class="gb">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pl">9.</td>
            <td class="team">
              Neuenburg Atomics 2             
            </td>
            <td class="g">0</td>
            <td class="v">0</td>
            <td class="pct">.000</td>
            <td class="gb">0</td>
        </tr>
</tbody></table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I forgot somehing, the url of the start.htm and end.htm are stored localy while the standings.php isn't. the point of this is to have an up to date league table, whithout doing it manually.

Comment: Well, that changes everything! Give me a minute please.

Comment: @Westerwave I've updated the answer, let me know if this isn't what you were looking for

Comment: After trying some things, do you mean to load the start/end.htm or the whole url?

Comment: @Westerwave I've added a full working example. Take care, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your example, but this isn't quite what i was looking for. I try to clarify this again in an edit

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding an iframe:

```
<iframe border="0" width="600px" height="auto" src="http://www.bwbsv.de/bbsb/service/extern/standings.php?start=http://www.bwbsv.de/bbsb/service/extern/start.htm&end=http://www.bwbsv.de/bbsb/service/extern/end.htm&t=401"></iframe>
```

You can change it's dimension for the best fit of the page.